# Bad-words filter with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, npm

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words and i created regex for filter special characters.

```
const Filter = require('bad-words');
const badWordsFilter = new Filter({replaceRegex:  /[A-Za-z0-9öÖÇçŞşĞğİıÜü_]/g});
badWordsFilter.addWords(['badword', 'şğ'])
```

If word doesn't contain turkish character, it works. But if i write turkish character like ş or ğ it is not filtering.

Is my regex wrong?

I found this code in documentation:

```
var filter = new Filter({ regex: /\*|\.|$/gi });
var filter = new Filter({ replaceRegex:  /[A-Za-z0-9가-힣_]/g }); 
//multilingual support for word filtering
```

Comment: How did you fix this problem? I have tried all cases from @antoni's answer. But some words which are in the blacklist are not recognized. For example, 'amık' is blocked, but 'amcık' is not blocked. I guess I broke regex somehow. Can you write your final regex here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have an encoding problem since your regex works out of your app, see here: https://regex101.com/r/VpItfH/3/.

So I think encoding your characters in your regex in your app may help:

**See the encoded regex result here: https://regex101.com/r/VpItfH/4/**

---

**More details**

Trying the following encoded regex in a PCRE regex engine will work (https://regex101.com/r/VpItfH/5):

```
/[A-Za-z0-9\x{f6}\x{d6}\x{c7}\x{e7}\x{15e}\x{15f}\x{11e}\x{11f}\x{130}\x{131}\x{dc}\x{fc}_]/g
```

but when selecting a javascript regex engine the `{`,`}` will break the unicode so you need to remove them and if the character is not recognized then replace `\x` with `\u0`. E.g. `\x{15e}` becomes `\u015e`

Then you can do the same match as when you use `/[A-Za-z0-9öÖÇçŞşĞğİıÜü_]/g`.

> **Note**: to get the unicode form of a character, you can do  `"Ğ".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);` and prefix it with `\x` or `\u0`.

Hope this can help, and at least acknowledge that you can encode characters inside a regex and still match the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with:

`var filter = new Filter({ replaceRegex:  /(\w+)/gi });`

For sure you have to use `replaceRegex` option.

---

The pattern matches everything case insentively.

Here's what `/(\w+)/gi` does descriptively (thanks to [regex101](http://regex101.com)):

1. 1st Capturing Group (\w+).

   1. **\w+** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
   2. **+ Quantifier** — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2. Global pattern flags

   1. **i modifier**: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
   2. **g modifier**: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Comment: i used your regex but still block only english characters. If word contains turkish character like ş, it is not filtering

Answer (score 1):

You need to make that regular expression [Unicode-aware](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex) by adding the `u` flag to it. More precisely, change `/[A-Za-z0-9öÖÇçŞşĞğİıÜü_]/g` into `/[A-Za-z0-9öÖÇçŞşĞğİıÜü_]/gu` (added a `u` at the end). This will work only in [modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags) (basically, all but Internet Explorer) though. There are [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/962603) as well, that you may want to consider if you want to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Encode your javascript file into utf-8 and update your meta tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Hoping this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am using it for Firebase Functions. I have only moderateWords function. It is filtering words which written in app